# Read random line from text file to text box in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on this program, and one of its features is to have a section where the program automatically randomly selects a line from a text file (what it contains is not important) and display this in a text box.

I have spend lots of time mixing and matching various code (streamReader etc.) but nothing I seem to try works.

this I know works lol: Random rand = new Random();

Also, please please PLEASE, do not just give me the link of some website to help me, because those websites are very confusing to me.

All I'm asking is that someone explain to me what I should be doing and what code i should have.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Answer (score 2):

This will return a random line from a file:

```
private static Random _rand = new Random();    

public static string GetRandomLine(string filename)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    var lineNumber = _rand.Next(0, lines.Length);

    return lines[lineNumber];
}
```

Comment: Please don't instantiate the `Random` instance inside the method as the method may be called multiple times in quick succession resulting in non-random values being returned. Always make `Random` a static class field to avoid these issues.

Comment: Also, the second parameter in `rnd.Next` is an **exclusive** upper bound. You need to remove the `-  1` to make it work.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks, I've corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To display a random line from a text file, you should:

- First load all the lines of text into an array *(each item in the
  array should be a line of text from the file)*.
- Then you want to generate a random number between 0 and the number
  of lines in the text. Use the `Random` class for that.
- And finally you want to print the line in the array using the
  generated random number.

Here's the pseudo-code to do the same thing:

```
Load TextFile
string[] text = Array of lines of text in TextFile
Random rnd = new Random object
int randomLine = New random number generated between 0 and (text.Length - 1)
Print text[randomLine]
```