# c# - how to read from random lines from textfile?

Tags: c#

I have my standard reading line by line code below:

```
    string strComment = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < userNames.Count; i++)
    {
        //strComment += ("@" + userNames[i] + " ");
        strComment += (userNames[i] + " ");
    }
```

I want to make it read random Usernames instead of line by line.

I've Tried my best, with failed attempt.

I wish somebody who can help me out.

Thank you,
regards.

Comment: This has already been answered, and your solution is found within: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745687/read-random-line-from-text-file-to-text-box-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745687/read-random-line-from-text-file-to-text-box-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It seems that he has already loaded the usernames in memory. The title is misleading.

Comment: Do you need to get every user only once? if not, then the link supplied by @JeremyWalker is enough

Comment: @Steve, to mark it as a duplicate of the post you indicated you should be sure that OP didn't want to return _all_ list values in random order, as I suspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
            string strComment = "";
            Random rndom = new Random();
            List<string> strResult = new List<string>();

            while (strResult.Count != userNames.Count) //Making sure every userNames is added
            {
                int a = rndom.Next(0, userNames.Count);
                if (!strResult.Contains(userNames.ElementAt(a))) //Making sure no duplicates
                    strResult.Add(userNames.ElementAt(a));

            }
            strComment = string.Join(" ", strResult); //Will return all results with space.
```

This code will return random userNames on your userNames variable, assuming its a List of string.

Comment: Thank you so much, works like charm.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
    static String GetUserNames(List<string> userNames)
    {
        List<string> userNamesCopy = userNames.ToList();

        string strComment = "";
        Random r = new Random();
        int userIndex;
        do
        {
            userIndex = r.Next(0, userNamesCopy.Count);
            strComment += (userNamesCopy[userIndex] + " ");
            userNamesCopy.RemoveAt(userIndex);
        }
        while (userNamesCopy.Count > 0);
        return strComment;
    }
```

to be used in your *Main* sub like:

```
string strComment = GetUserNames(userNames);
```

Comment: @Johnfabric, did you try my code?